¿Existen diferencias en el uso de forms.Form y forms.ModelForm si quiero crear una vista de edición?
Estoy haciendo un formulario en django que funcione como una edit view, inicialmente estaba usando forms.ModelForm sin embargo tuve que pasar todo a forms.Form porque no aceptaba algunos formatos con la fecha y me mandaba muchos errores, por lo que decidí la opción de forms.Form.
Esta vista funcionó bien para mí cuando estaba usando forms.ModelForms
def FianzasEditar(request, id):
fianza = get_object_or_404(Fianza, pk=id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FianzaForm(request.POST, instance=fianza)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('fianzas:fianzas_list')
else:
    form = FianzaForm(instance=fianza)
return render(request, 'fianzas-editar.html', {'form': form})

Pero así como lo tengo con  forms.Form el formulario me envía errores de que no debo usar la instancia, y si no la uso, esta vista ya no funcionaría como vista de edición, solo cargaría el formulario como si fuera una create view.
¿Para las vistas es diferente el procesamiento cuando se usa forms.Form y cuando se usa forms.ModelForm?
